# How to drop into a repl from within a Clojure command line application?

Tags: clojure, command-line-interface, read-eval-print-loop

I'm writing a Clojure CLI application, and I would like to allow a command to be given to it which would drop people into the clojure.main REPL.

Does anyone know how I can go about doing that? My effort have not been fruitful.

EDIT:

My problem is made worse by the fact that my CLI takes piped input. Here's an example of what I'd like to work:

```
(ns playground.core
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (with-open [r (io/reader *in*)]
    (doseq [line (line-seq r)]
      (println line)))
;; Drop in repl after having read the input and printed its content)
```

I then call this as such:

```
cat ./somefile.txt | lein trampoline run
```

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate because that question does not address the idea that the repl does not need to be the first consumer of input to the program and does not need to be started when the program starts.

Comment: Yes, my question is specifically trying to get an answer where the REPL is not the first thing to start. The program first starts, accepts inputs from *in*, do more things, and then it needs to transition into a REPL.

Comment: The CLI REPL operates over stdin and stdout, so does piping. Maybe you should use nREPL / socket REPL with pREPL and connect remotely? This keeps your stdin open for your file pipe but allows you to connect a REPL remotely. Alternatively you could read stdin _then_ start a REPL as mentioned in other answers.

Comment: @Olical I could go that route, but the thing is, I'm done with stdin by the time I drop in the repl. But it seems something about stdin is causing the REPL to close right after it starts.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe starting a headless REPL and have two separate steps might work for you?

**Step 1**

Launch a headless REPL, wait for it to start

```
$ lein repl :headless :host 0.0.0.0 :port 9000
nREPL server started on port 9000 on host 0.0.0.0 - nrepl://0.0.0.0:9000
```

**Step 2**

In another shell, send the commands to the REPL using your command:

```
$ cat test.txt 
(def hello "Hello world!")

$ cat test.txt | lein repl :connect 0.0.0.0:9000
Connecting to nREPL at 0.0.0.0:9000
REPL-y 0.3.7, nREPL 0.2.12
Clojure 1.8.0
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_181-8u181-b13-1ubuntu0.18.04.1-b13
    Docs: (doc function-name-here)
          (find-doc "part-of-name-here")
  Source: (source function-name-here)
 Javadoc: (javadoc java-object-or-class-here)
    Exit: Control+D or (exit) or (quit)
 Results: Stored in vars *1, *2, *3, an exception in *e

pipetest.core=> (def hello "Hello world!")
#'pipetest.core/hello
pipetest.core=> Bye for now!
```

**Step 3**

You can connect to the REPL, continue after the state changes from the previous step, but now you can use it to interact.

```
$ lein repl :connect 0.0.0.0:9000
Connecting to nREPL at 0.0.0.0:9000
REPL-y 0.3.7, nREPL 0.2.12
Clojure 1.8.0
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_181-8u181-b13-1ubuntu0.18.04.1-b13
    Docs: (doc function-name-here)
          (find-doc "part-of-name-here")
  Source: (source function-name-here)
 Javadoc: (javadoc java-object-or-class-here)
    Exit: Control+D or (exit) or (quit)
 Results: Stored in vars *1, *2, *3, an exception in *e

pipetest.core=> (str hello "!!!")
"Hello world!!!!"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just call `clojure.main/repl` from your program and it will start listening to stdin and 'repl'ying to it ;-) at that point the repl will start

```
user> (clojure.main/repl)
```

then i type into the terminal `(+ 1 2 3)`

```
user=> 6
user=>
```

so i had a repl in a repl going there to simulate the case where the person using your program types the start repl command.

for making a human friendly repl experience the [rebl-readline](https://github.com/bhauman/rebel-readline#quick-usage) project adds a lot to calling clojure.main/repl:

```
(rebel-readline.core/with-line-reader
  (rebel-readline.clojure.line-reader/create
    (rebel-readline.clojure.service.local/create))
  (clojure.main/repl
     :prompt (fn []) ;; prompt is handled by line-reader
     :read (rebel-readline.clojure.main/create-repl-read)))
```

---

Since your program has essentially two phases,

1. read things from standard input forever or until standard input is permanently closed.
2. once the program is dead or standard input is no longer available, whichever happens first read more from standard input.

You may want to (or perhaps you already have) a thing that breaks out of the `with-open` once some special line is sent. once this is received completely exit the `line-seq` and `with-open`. then start the repl so it can grab the input file-descriptor.

---

once you make the program get input to the repl, your piping issue can be solved in the enclosing shell command. `cat` takes a special argument `-` (just a dash nothing else with spaces on either side) that says "stop here and read from the keyboard until Crtl-d is pressed"

```
~ » cat a-file - | cat
hello im a line from a file
hello
hello
```

in this example it read a line from a file, passed it to the cat command (replace with your program), then it read the word `hello` from the keyboard and printed it as well (so you see it twice on the screen)

Comment: I pipe input into my Clojure CLI. Such as `cat somefile.txt | lein trampoline run`. In that case, neither calling `clojure.main/repl` or using rebel-readline works. If I don't pipe input and just run `lein trampoline run` it does work though. Any idea how I can drop into the repl given I'm piping input?

Comment: @DidierA. added the bit about getting around the piped input and some opinions on breaking it out of the read-line